# Fastest way to remove a color from a UIImage?

Tags: ios, core-image

I have an image that I'm using to create an anaglyph by splitting it into separate red and cyan versions and setting a parallax between them.

The source image is 1146 x 580 (at retina resolution). I'm using a CIColorMatrix to create each image. Here's the code for the Cyan version which removes all of the red.

```
-(UIImage *)createCyan:(UIImage *)anImage
{

    CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:anImage.CGImage];

    CIFilter *matrixFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix"];
    [matrixFilter setDefaults];
    [matrixFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [matrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputRVector"];
    [matrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:1 Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputGVector"];
    [matrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:1 W:0] forKey:@"inputBVector"];
    [matrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:0 W:1] forKey:@"inputAVector"];

    CIImage *outputImage = [matrixFilter outputImage];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]]; 

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
}
```

The problem is that this takes over a second to process. I need to find a much faster means (if one exists) of accomplishing the same thing.

Is there a better method?

Comment: Could you create a color cube to do it? There's a WWDC 2013 (or 2012) video about CIFilters and Core Image in general. They show some cool ways to speed up image processing by creating their own color maps instead of using built in ones.

Comment: @Fogmeister, the one you mean is session 511 from 2012. It's excellent. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=511 Core Image Techniques

Answer (score 0):

The issue with speed is not so much the filter, but that you're initializing a `CIContext`, a very expensive process, repeatedly. Create the `CIContext` beforehand, and your problem is solved.